# I want to publish a common action to the open graph from my android app. Its not working

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

- I am using facebook sdk 3.0.
- My app type is set to game.
- I have the proper "publish_actions" permission.
- My token is still valid.
- I am trying to post a score to "me/scores"
  using

  ```
      Bundle fbParams = new Bundle();
      fbParams.putString("score", "" + highScore);
      Request request = new Request(session,
          "me/scores",
          fbParams,
          HttpMethod.POST,
          new Request.Callback() {
          @Override
          public void onCompleted(Response response) {
               Log.d("com", "done");
              FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
              if (error != null) {
                  Log.d("com", "Posting Score to Facebook failed: " +
                      error.getErrorMessage());
              } else {
                  Log.d("com", "Score posted successfully to Facebook");
              }
          }
      }
      );
      request.executeAsync();
  ```

According to the facebook dev site, common actions don't need prior setup. A request just needs to be made from the app using http post and then the action appears in your list of actions. But it is not working.

A couple questions:

- Do I need a namespace if I am not creating custom actions?
- I have not submitted my app to the appstore yet, is that a prerequisite for getting my objects reviewed?
- can I use the graph explorer to request the object get reviewed?

Comment: So I was able to GET the POSTS from my app using the graph exlorer so I geuss they are getting sent. I figured you'de see some sign that a score was sent even if it didn't generate a story to my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to GET the POSTS from my app using the graph exlorer so I geuss they are getting sent. I figured you'de see some sign that a score was sent even if it didn't generate a story to my friends.